# Delete and duplicate rows in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

In Python, let's say I have a 1366x768 numpy array. And I want to delete each second row from it (0th row remains, 1st removed, 2nd remains, 3rd removed.. and so on), and replace the empty space with a duplicate from the row which was before it (the undeleted row) at the same time.

Is it possible in numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach -

```
a[::2].repeat(2,axis=0)
```

To make the changes in the array, assign it back.

Sample run -

```
In [105]: a
Out[105]: 
array([[2, 5, 1, 1],
       [2, 0, 2, 5],
       [1, 1, 5, 7],
       [0, 7, 1, 8],
       [8, 5, 2, 3],
       [2, 1, 0, 6],
       [5, 6, 1, 6],
       [7, 1, 4, 7],
       [3, 8, 1, 4],
       [5, 8, 8, 8]])

In [106]: a[::2].repeat(2,axis=0)
Out[106]: 
array([[2, 5, 1, 1],
       [2, 5, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 5, 7],
       [1, 1, 5, 7],
       [8, 5, 2, 3],
       [8, 5, 2, 3],
       [5, 6, 1, 6],
       [5, 6, 1, 6],
       [3, 8, 1, 4],
       [3, 8, 1, 4]])
```

If we care about performance, here's another approach using [`NumPy strides`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) -

```
def strided_app(a):
    m0,n0 = a.strides
    m,n = a.shape
    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
    return strided(a,shape=(m//2,2,n),strides=(2*m0,0,n0)).reshape(-1,n)
```

Sample run -

```
In [154]: a
Out[154]: 
array([[4, 8, 7, 7],
       [5, 5, 1, 7],
       [1, 8, 1, 3],
       [6, 6, 5, 6],
       [0, 2, 6, 3],
       [6, 6, 8, 7],
       [7, 6, 8, 1],
       [7, 8, 8, 2],
       [4, 0, 2, 8],
       [5, 8, 1, 4]])

In [155]: strided_app(a)
Out[155]: 
array([[4, 8, 7, 7],
       [4, 8, 7, 7],
       [1, 8, 1, 3],
       [1, 8, 1, 3],
       [0, 2, 6, 3],
       [0, 2, 6, 3],
       [7, 6, 8, 1],
       [7, 6, 8, 1],
       [4, 0, 2, 8],
       [4, 0, 2, 8]])
```

Timings -

```
In [156]: arr = np.arange(1000000).reshape(1000, 1000)

# Proposed soln-1
In [157]: %timeit arr[::2].repeat(2,axis=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 ms per loop

# @Psidom 's soln
In [158]: %timeit arr[1::2] = arr[::2]
1000 loops, best of 3: 928 µs per loop

In [159]: arr = np.arange(1000000).reshape(1000, 1000)

# Proposed soln-2
In [160]: %timeit strided_app(arr)
1000 loops, best of 3: 830 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have an even number of rows, in which case, you can use assignment (assign the odd rows values to corresponding even rows):

```
arr = np.array([[1,4],[3,1],[2,3],[2,2]])
arr[1::2] = arr[::2]
arr
#array([[1, 4],
#       [1, 4],
#       [2, 3],
#       [2, 3]])
```

This avoids copying the entire array, but doesn't work if the array has odd number of rows.

*Timing*: Here is a comparison of the timing, the assignment does seem faster.

```
arr = np.arange(1000000).reshape(1000, 1000)

%timeit arr[::2].repeat(2,axis=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 913 µs per loop

%timeit arr[1::2] = arr[::2]
1000 loops, best of 3: 655 µs per loop
```

Comment: Looks pretty efficient for in-place assignment.

Comment: @Divakar It could be. Kind of awkward only work for even number of rows array though. I'll add some timing.

Comment: Added another approach with `strides`. It's just crazy that `strides` is beating a simple assignment step.

Comment: @Divakar That's quite impressive. `strides` is still a quite new concept to me. -

Answer (score 0):

This works for both even and an odd number of rows.

```
for i in range(1,len(a),2):
    a[i] = a[i-1]
```